# How map image through a lookup table?

Tags: opencv

I thought this should be easy (and it probably is) but I can't figure out how to map the pixels in a 8-bit grey image through a lookup table with 256 values between 0 and 255. I have searched on the net and I have found a function called cvLut() but cannot find that function in current opencv, is it removed or renamed. How do I do the mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the mapping by using cvLUT or cv::LUT (C/C++)

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=lut#lut

Calling the function is trivial and is explained in the documentation.

Comment: thanks! I did a search for it on on my ubuntu 10.04 in /usr/include/opencv but didn't get any match, but now I tried again and it was there, must have fogot to do grep -i the first time maybe ...

Comment: Link dead, please update.